# Problems building ORMLite queries using version 4.48

Tags: java, android, ormlite, query-builder

I have problems in upgrading ormlite for android from version 4.47 to version 4.48

Everything works fine in 4.47 but in 4.48 launching application I'm having this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The SQL statement has not been finished
    since there are previous operations still waiting for clauses.
```

The problem is in this line of code:

```
final PreparedQuery<Intervento> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
```

Here is the source code of my method:

```
final Where<Intervento, Integer> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.eq(Intervento.ESEGUITO_FIELD_NAME, false).and();
where.eq(Intervento.ENABLED_FIELD_NAME, true).and();
if (whereFields!=null){
    for (String key : whereFields.keySet()){
        if (whereFields.get(key)!=null){                
            SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
            selectArg.setValue(whereFields.get(key).getClass().cast(whereFields.get(key)));
            where.like(key,selectArg).and();
        }   
    }
}

final PreparedQuery<Intervento> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
final AndroidCompiledStatement compiledStatement = (AndroidCompiledStatement)preparedQuery.compile(DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mContext).getConnectionSource().getReadOnlyConnection(),StatementType.SELECT);
return compiledStatement.getCursor();
```

**Edit:**

I think it is possibly due to the last `.and()` added in for cycle...  But it has stop working in this latest version upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think it is possibly due to the last .and() added in for cycle... But it has stop working in this latest version upgrade.

I'm not 100% sure why it *was* working at all under 4.47 but 4.48 added some features in the `.and()` chaining department so maybe now it is better checking for this error.  Right now you have dangling `.and()` statements.

Instead of putting the `.and()` at the *end* of your lines, you should move them to the start of the lines.  Right now, if `whereFields` is `null` then you would build a query with the following:

```
where.eq(Intervento.ESEGUITO_FIELD_NAME, false).and();
where.eq(Intervento.ENABLED_FIELD_NAME, true).and();
```

If [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) actually generated the SQL this would be something like:

```
WHERE eseguito = false AND enabled = true AND
```

Notice the dangling `AND` at the end of the query which is invalid.  If you put the `.and()` when before you add another SQL clause, then this would not be an issue.

```
where.eq(Intervento.ESEGUITO_FIELD_NAME, false); // no .and() here
// .and() at the start of a new clause
where.and().eq(Intervento.ENABLED_FIELD_NAME, true);
```

Then inside the `whereFields != null` and the loop you would do something like:

```
where.and().like(key,selectArg);
```

So you would add the `AND key like ?` each time there is another key.